# FFMEG multiple frames extraction

Tags: ffmpeg

I need a command (if there is any) that will allow me to extract frames at different time offsets. Currently I'm able to extract them one by one using ss command.

Example of current command:

```
C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -i %1 -ss %2  -vframes 1 -s %3x%4 -f image2 %5 -hide_banner -loglevel panic
```

This works very slowly on large number of time offsets.

Answer (score 3):

Put the `-ss` option before the `-i` option to get `ffmpeg` to seek to the nearest keyframe and decode from there, rather than decoding from the beginning of the file each time.